# System Information on terminal

Tags: linux, bash

This might come across as a silly question but is there any shell that will allow me to get the system information as the shell is active?
What I mean is a shell like bash or similar that will show me the current cpu,memory, io and network usage at the top or anywhere but being parallel to the console.
Something like:

```
---------------------------------
| CPU:3% I/O:4% Mem free: 1.5GB |
=================================
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |
| user@server ~ $: ls           |
| folder1 folder2 some_file1    |
| user@server ~ $:_             |
---------------------------------
```

I'm looking for something that is console only so that I can get its statistics from say an ssh session.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415293/fixed-line-on-top-of-zsh-in-terminal

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @ewwhite Because I need to keep an eye on the web-server on high-load and high-traffic times and keeping multiple ssh windows open with each running different tools is a bit inefficient.

Comment: @ddrjm Watching a terminal for CPU and load information is also inefficient. Are you sure you're not looking for a simple monitoring/alerting solution? Something like [**Monit**](https://mmonit.com/monit/) is very easy to install and is possibly the better way to keep track of these conditions.

Comment: @ewwhite Monit sounds great but is it secure as in, needing to auth and maybe go to a specific port to check the system?

Comment: @ddrjm It's not something you really log into. Use Monit to alert you (email) of high load/CPU conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [byobu](http://byobu.co/) - its customizable to your needs and also comes with a good default configuration.

Comment: Mind = blown. This might just be what I'm looking for. Can this be used via ssh? I'm currently running windows and this would help cut the number of putty windows down by a lot

Comment: @ddrjm byobu is a wrapper for [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) / [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and it can be used by ssh (if it runs on the remote host).